# Make an input field use a certain keyboard? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, keyboard

I was wondering if it was possible to have an input field use a certain input method, and if the user is using a different keyboard on their computer, it would think the user is using that certain keyboard, or it would convert the keystrokes. Not really sure how else to explain it.

For example, if I have the English keyboard activated and press e-x-a-m-p-l-e, it would show up as "example". If I have, let's say.., the Greek keyboard activated and typed the same thing, it would show up as "εχαμπλε". So, how would I go about making an input field convert "εχαμπλε" to "example"? So that even though I have the Greek keyboard activated it would still register in English?

I don't know if this is really easy to do or really hard, I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript, so I have no idea how difficult it is to do this, or if it's even possible. I tried looking it up but I had no results.

Comment: u want to help/force user to type in a specific language like English. so if he try to type in ie. Greek then it shows it in English right?

Comment: Exactly, basically make the input field / form think that the user is typing with an english keyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to help/force user to type in a specific language like English. So, if he/she tries to type in ie. Greek then it shows it in English, right?

If yes you should do a lots of coding. I mean if you want to convert 5 language to English you should have their keys like the word "H" in the keyboard would be another words in other languages. And also we have different keyboard layouts in different keyboards. The word "H" would have different words in other languages.

But still you have some hope.

Let's say you want to only to convert Greek to English. So you should have a map of which words should be converted to what, and then yes you can do it like:

```
var keymap=[{"from":"a","to":"ε"},{"from":"b","to":"χ"},.....];
```

then you can check an input with JavaScript an try to check and change the words when needed, using 'Onchange' event.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible in xml use xml and write this code in xml page and use xml api in html page to run this code.Change this code according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Translation code="200" lang="en-ru">
<text>Быть или не быть?</text>
<text>Вот в чем вопрос.</text>

</Translation>
```